# PHP Switch with simple strings not working

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = basename($url).PHP_EOL;

switch ($url) {
    case 'digital-marketing-and-seo':
        $new_url = "Digital Marketing & SEO";
        break;
    case 'websites-digital-destinations':
        $new_url = "Websites & Digital Destinations";
        break;
    case 'brand-identity-evolution':
        $new_url = "Brand Identity & Evolution";
        break;
    case 'strategy-consulting':
        $new_url = "Strategy & Consulting";
        break;
    case 'government-universities':
        $new_url = "Government & Universities";
        break;
    case 'hospitality-travel':
        $new_url = "Hospitality & Travel";
        break;
    case 'architecture-engineering':
        $new_url = "Architecture & Engineering";
        break;
    case 'wine-spirits':
        $new_url = "Wine & Spirits";
        break;
    default:
        $new_url = '';
        echo 'default derp';
}
```

So I have this block of code and it will not work for me. The url can say exactly what is in the case and it will default. I'm trying to get url structures to build out a shortcode and I need it to match what is entered.

I determined that if I enter just add a variable for a string for $url = 'brand-identity-evolution'; The switch works. I made sure it's a string with is_string function and can't figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added a `PHP_EOL` at the end of the URL, so all of your cases will fail because you're not checking for that. Remove your `PHP_EOL` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Awesome! It's been a long day. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please be sure to mark this as the answer if it fixes your issue

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't let me last night due to the quickness of the answer.